# Various activities, various intents, failed at name app

Tags: android, android-intent, title

I have some intents to execute different activities, my problem is that when I run the app in the device, eclipse install it with the name of the last activity. For example:

We have, three activities: 1 - 2 - 3. The first is the main activity (1), it name is Noow but I have an Intent to another activity (3) to get the location and return the data to (1). The app installed is named as getLocation (3) and it must have the name of the (1).

This is the manifiest xml file. Could someone help me with this? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="victor.martin.noow"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="victor.martin.noow.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="victor.martin.noow.LoginScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="victor.martin.noow.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="victor.martin.noow.getLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/getLocationActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: bro you have lanucher category in all activities, only 1 is laucnher activity, rest should be some other category, or no category at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the SDK will use the name of the activity having the LAUNCHER property:

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The simplest solution would be to delete the LoginScreenActivity label and set it programatically. In this case the label provided in the  tag will be used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there has to be one activity set as main activity i.e launcher activity. What you have done is set all activities as main which is incorrect in all terms of programming logic.

The activity with

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

gets the by default name, and by convention in your case after reading your xml the last activity got default name.

Comment: Thank you, I will delete it and check the results. I believe that I need to declare all the intents I used.